# In VB6, how do I call a COM object requiring a pointer to an object?

Tags: com, vb6, interop

I'm having trouble with a .NET Assembly that is com visible, and calling certain methods from VB6.
What I have found is that if the parameters are well defined types, (e.g. string), calls work fine.  If they are higher level objects, it raises a runtime error '438' suggesting that the property or method is not present.  I suspect that this is a question of having the correct signature on the call, but I can't see how to do this correctly.

I believe that I've done everything correct on the .NET side (ComVisible, public interfaces, etc. and even have it down to a simple enough case).

Looking at the output from the typelib viewer, I have the following:

```
dispinterface ISimple {
properties:
methods:
    [id(0x60020000)]
    void Add([in] ISimpleMember* member);
    [id(0x60020001)]
    ISimpleMember* Create();
};
```

OK.  So I have 2 methods in my ISimple interface.  One takes an ISimpleMember (Add), whilst the other, returns an ISimpleMember.

The corresponding code in VB looks like this:

```
Dim item As ISimpleMember
Dim simple As simple
Set item = New SimpleMember
item.S1 = "Hello"
item.S2 = "World"
Set simple = New simple
simple.Add (item)           <---- This raised the run time error 438
Set item = simple.Create    <---- This works fine, returning me an ISimpleMember
```

I've tried a couple of things:
1. Dim item as SimpleMember (makes no difference)
2. simple.Add(ObjPtr(item)) - Syntax error
3. simple.Add(ByRef item) - Syntax error

Basically, The run time error is the same as if I had 
simple.AMethodThatIHaventWritten()

Also, If I browse References in the VB6 Environment, The Add method is well defined:

Sub Add(member As SimpleMember)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer I believe.  It was very simple:
When calling a SubRoutine, I shouldn't put the name in braces.  the call should have been:

```
simple.add member
```

rather than

```
simple.add(member)
```

If I change it to a function (i.e. return a value rather than void) the braces are necessary

This seems to work

Comment: This error should be easy to spot.  The IDE will try to tell you what you've asked for by inserting a space in front of the value expression you've entered.  For a function call no such space is there (and if you enter one it gets removed).  Subtle?  Not to anyone who has written in VB6 for more than a day or so.

Answer (score 0):

(Probably) The top 3 VB6 coding mistakes made by devs who now mainly code in C#, Javascript etc. Are:-

1. Placing `;` at the end of lines.  Its a syntax error very easily spotted and picked up the compiler.
2. Not placing `Then` on the other side of an `If` condition expression.  Again its a syntax error.
3. Calling a method without retrieving a value and yet using ( ) to enclose the parameter list.  With multiple parameters this is a syntax error and easily found.  With only one parameter the use of ( ) is interpreted as an expression.  Its the result of the ( ) expression which is passed as parameter.  This causes problems when ByRef is expected by the callee.